# decimal data entery in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-plugins

```
public Decimal SalePrice { get; set; }
```

and

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.SalePrice) %>
```

What is a good way to ensure validation  or proper input entry from the user? Things like only allow numeric enteries and upto two decimal points?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A regular expression like the following should work:

```
\A\d+(\.\d{1,2})?\Z
```

This matches input like:

```
2.00
25.70
04.15
2.50
525.43
423.3
52
```

And, as Mike suggested, you could use this in a data validation attribute:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\A\d+(\.\d{1,2})?\Z", ErrorMessage="Please enter a numeric value with up to two decimal places.")]
public Decimal SalePrice { get; set; }
```

**Edit:** In response to your two questions:

**1) This validates on submit right and not when we lose focus of that field?**

Assuming all you've added is the attribute, then yes validation occurs on submit. Technically, validation occurs once the form parameters are bound to the model. However, to actually make use of this, you need to check the validation parameter in your controller:

```
public ActionResult MyController(MyModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // Return view with the now-invalid model
        // if you've placed error messages on the view, they will be displayed
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

To have the validation occur client-side in addition to server-side, you'd need to use javascript. A basic example of this using Microsoft AJAX validation is at [Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx).

**2) Can you show me the regex where the max entry cannot exceed 100.00 and min entry cannot be below 1.00**

You could probably do this in regex somehow, but regex isn't really designed for anything more than pattern matching. A better way to do this would be to add a range validation attribute, in addition to your regex attribute. So now your property would look like:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\A\d+(\.\d{1,2})?\Z", ErrorMessage="Please enter a numeric value with up to two decimal places.")]
[Range(1.00m, 100.00m)]
public Decimal SalePrice { get; set; }
```

The above code is untested but the general approach should work.

Comment: Thanks and great explanation by the way. I will definitely try this out.

Answer (score 1):

You could  use a regex string to validate the input on the client and server side.

If you put a RegularExpression attribute on your controller action you can specify using a regex string what format that field needs to follow. By using that attribute you will gain both client and server side validation (assuming you are using MVC 2.0 or later).

```
[RegularExpression("*YourRegexExpression*", ErrorMessage="You must provide a decimal value.")]
```

I hope that helps.

See Scott Gu's blog post that talks about model validation for more information.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx

Mike